# DateTime.ToLocalTime() in winter/summer time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am using `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` to convert dates from UTC to local time. My time zone is GMT+1(Belgrade, Budapest, Lubjna...), it is set properly in Windows Settings (XP).

Last weekend in our time zone we changed to winter time to summer time, it means, we set back local time by one hour.

As I see ToLocalTime method behaves strange from that moment. When I use it to convert dates that are after this winter time change, it works great, like this:

```
var utcDate2 = new DateTime(2011, 11, 2, 9, 0, 0,DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

`utcDate1.ToLocalTime()` value is: `2011.11.02. 10:00:00` it is correct

Burt when I want to convert a date before this change (e.g. a date from summer time) it gives back a bad value like this:

```
var utcDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 10, 23, 9, 0, 0,DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

`utcDate2.ToLocalTime()` value is: `2011.10.23. 10:00:00` it is incorrect It should be 2011.10.23. 11:00:00

What should I do to get correct values? How should I use ToLocalTime that also adjust winter/summer time?

Comment: It's not at all clear what's wrong - you've shown the creation of two UTC date times, but not what happens when you convert them to local time. Please give a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry folks, I updated, some ctrl+c, ctrl+v problem

Comment: There is a difference of 7 days between your two examples. What exactly are you asking? Since you have already adjusted your local clocks you will have to adjust the local time. I do not believe UTC is DST aware, there is a DST version of it, you might want to use that depending if DST should be applied locally or not. Your second example actually is correct per the current DST rules on your computer.

Comment: they want to determine what the local datetime would have been at a point prior to the day light savings like shift.  The problem is the library only does the shift using the current rules in affect "TODAY"...

Comment: Ramhound, first date is in summer time of the year, second is in winter time of the year.

Comment: @jsobo: Note that there is a difference between the *current rules* and the *current state*. The library uses the current rules, but it uses the state of the date that you are converting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx

> On Windows XP systems, the ToLocalTime method recognizes only the
>   current adjustment rule when converting from UTC to local time. As a
>   result, conversions for periods before the current adjustment rule
>   came into effect may not accurately reflect the difference between UTC
>   and local time.

So you will have to find another way to figure it out.

Comment: It is a very sad news for me :(

Comment: On the other hand, I'd expect 2011 to reflect the current adjustment rule - this should be a problem for *historical* data, not the current year.

Comment: As my example shows, it is a problem for the current year also

Comment: Do you mean that the adjustment rule has changed since the adjustment happened three days ago? Otherwise it *is* the current adjustment rule that is used.

Comment: 3 days ago there was the summer time/winter time change in my time zone. If I convert now 'a date to local time that is in summer time' it gives back an incorrect value

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the time zone data on your system *may* be out of date - or it's due to the limitation jsobo mentioned.

One option you *might* want to (cautiously) pursue is using my date/time API, [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com). This has conversion to/from `DateTime` so you *could* use `DateTime` elsewhere in your code, although obviously I believe your code would be clearer if you used Noda Time throughout :)

Noda Time isn't "v1.0-ready" yet, but mostly because of a few missing features. Whether you're willing to take the risk of a non-v1.0 open source project or not is up to you, of course, but I'd be very happy to help with any issues you run into. (I'm really trying to find real-life use cases, so if there are any missing features you need, I may well be able to implement them in anticipation of others needing the same thing.)

Noda Time uses the zoneinfo time zone database, not the one built into Windows, so it shouldn't have the same issues.

To check, you'd use code like this:

```
DateTimeZone belgradeZone = DateTimeZone.ForId("Europe/Belgrade"); // Or whatever
// Alternatively...
DateTimeZone localZone = DateTimeZone.SystemDefault;
ZonedDateTime utc = new ZonedDateTime(2011, 10, 23, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.Utc);
ZonedDateTime belgrade = new ZonedDateTime(utc.ToInstant(), belgradeZone);
Console.WriteLine(belgrade.LocalDateTime);
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it use a local database or some on the internet?

Comment: @Tom see [here](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) for information about the database.

Answer (score 1):

I use the same time zone, and when I try it I get the correct values:

```
var utcDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 10, 23, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Console.WriteLine(utcDate1);
Console.WriteLine(utcDate1.ToLocalTime());

var utcDate2 = new DateTime(2011, 11, 2, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
Console.WriteLine(utcDate2);
Console.WriteLine(utcDate2.ToLocalTime());
```

Output:

```
2011-10-23 09:00:00
2011-10-23 11:00:00
2011-11-02 09:00:00
2011-11-02 10:00:00
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using? This may well be XP-specific.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention that. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

.NET does some calculation behind the scenes. I recommend reading [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/24/55413.aspx) from Raymond Chen about implicit time zone conversions.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answere. Also the link is broken